# save regular data to file

Tags: java, file

I am new in java!
I use this code to write data to a .txt file:

```
try { 
String content = "This is the content to write into file";
File file = new File("/users/mkyong/filename.txt");

// if file doesnt exists, then create it

if ( !file.exists() ) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter( file.getAbsoluteFile() );
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( fw );
bw.write( content );
    bw.NewLine();
bw.close();
System.out.println("Done");
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

First name        Lastname        Registration Number

joe

max

1238

I want to store each data below the its name:

I want to like this:

FName  LName    Reg_Num

joe                      max                        1238

thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? BTW it's great that you explore Java. Once you know how IO works, you can use something like `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, string);` from the http://commons.apache.org/io/ project.

Comment: how come the code even compiles with this "bw.NewLine();"

Comment: problem is joe and max and number should be exactly under the firstname  and lastname and reg_num. but each of them is in an new line, and if i dont use newline method firstname and last name would be connect each!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **\t** to add tab between the fields. The sample code could be something like :

```
    try {
        String firstName = "Joe";
        String lastName = "Doe";
        String regNum = "123";

        File file = new File("/home/parvin/Desktop/filename.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("FirstName\t LastName\t RegNum\t \n");
        bw.write(firstName + "\t" + lastName + "\t" + regNum + "\t" + "\n");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @APoliteBoy Don't forget to accept an answer if you are happy with it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

That code should output "This is the content to write into file" into the text file. Where are all these names coming from?

For tabulation in Java [see this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585337/how-to-use-tab-space-while-writing-in-text-file).

Comment: these names come from a simple form.

Comment: Impossible to infer as much from the code you posted. Anyway, @parvin seems to have gone trough the trouble of laying it out quite neatly :)