# Java BufferedWriter is not handling tab space properly

Tags: java, file-io

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream(), encoding)); 

public void write(final List<Column> columnsList) throws IOException {
        String data = null;
        int length = columnsList.size();
        int writeIndex = 0;
        for (Column cd : columnsList) {
            data = cd.getData();            
            writer.write(data);
            writer.write(getDelimiter()); // it will return '\t'
        }
        writer.write("\n");
    }
```

The above code is not placing the tab space in file, and in actual it writes `\t` in file.
When I write the file with hard coded "\t", it really does write tab space. But I am receiving the "\t" delimiter from web-end. 
I am just picking this delimiter and writing with writer. But when I open the file in notepad, "\t" is actually written in the file instead of TAB SPACE

I am closing the writer in other method., so no worry about closing the writer

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson why ?? isn't \t a valid java escape sequence ?

Comment: It really won't do this. I suspect the problem is in how you're viewing the file, which you haven't told us.

Comment: How are you verifying the contents? Are you actually viewing it, or just reading it back somehow?

Comment: No, `"\\t` would print the actual text `"\t"`. What you want to write is the tab escape character.

Comment: Are you initialising that writer?

Comment: I tried with a simple code `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("c:\\ak\\1.txt")));
  writer.write("\t");
  writer.close();` and its writing `tab` in the file.

Comment: @PermGenError  Conceded.  Should have stuck with the first comment only.  :P

Comment: @JonSkeet, I am viewing this file as text file in note pad

Comment: @Apurv, when I write the file with hard coded "\t", it really does write tab space. But I am receiving the "\t" delimiter from web-end. I am just picking this delimiter and writing with writer. But when I open the file in notepad, "\t" is actually written in the file instead of TAB SPACE

Comment: @Pomy You need to update your question with complete details, only then you can expect accurate answer.

Comment: @Pomy Please share more details about the `getDelimiter()` method. There are good chances that this method is returning `\\t` instead of `\t`. You can also try printing the return value of this method on console.

Comment: @Apurv, when I print getDelimiter(), it simply prints \t. But when I debug the value it shows me "\\t"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am Quite SUre the `getDelimiter()` will return the "\t" Which are two characters.

You can verify it by `getDelimiter().toCharArray();`

**Simple Solution is that use like following code snippet**

```
if (getDelimiter().equalsIgnoreCase("\\t")) then use String.valueOf('\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not initialize BufferedWriter object.
Here is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/) of how to write file in java using bufferedwriter

Comment: I have just shown what I was actually doing and what acutlly happening. So it is obvious that I have initialized the BufferedWriter

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it as well.

Working fine! Check this [how to use "tab space" while writing in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585337/how-to-use-tab-space-while-writing-in-text-file) post as you may need some configuration.

Post the whole method for this for more info

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("bot.txt", true); //true tells to append data.
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

out.write("bbb" + "\t"+"aaa");
out.close();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this issue, maybe you are missing something before initializing the BufferedWriter

[how to use "tab space" while writing in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585337/how-to-use-tab-space-while-writing-in-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Your writer definition is not complete, so we do not know which underlying stream/writer you use.

This example works for me:

```
BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
writer.write("a");
writer.write("\t");
writer.write("b");
writer.close();
```

It prints a tab character between "a" and "b".

Answer (score -3):

You should call writer.close();

you do it?

Comment: That wouldn't explain seeing `"\t"` in the file.