# What does \t represent in txt file?

Tags: python, text, pandas

I am opening a txt file using pandas and where there should be a column break in the file there is a `\t` instead.

I am reading in the file like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'file.txt')
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
1           Band 1\t 0.428944\t0.843916\t0.689923\t0                    
2           Band 2\t-0.000000\t0.689320\t0.513170\t0                   
3           Band 3\t 0.336438\t0.743478\t0.592622\t0                    
4           Band 4\t 0.313259\t0.678561\t0.525667\t0                     
5           Band 5\t 0.374522\t0.746828\t0.583513\t0
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
1           Band 1   0.428944  0.843916  0.689923                     
2           Band 2  -0.000000  0.689320  0.513170                  
3           Band 3   0.336438  0.743478  0.592622                    
4           Band 4   0.313259  0.678561  0.525667                    
5           Band 5   0.374522  0.746828  0.583513
```

I am new to using txt files in python, do I perhaps have to set a delimiter of some sort?

Using `print(repr(open(r'D:\Sheyenne\Statistics\NDVI_allotment\Text\A_Annex2.txt').read(42)))` returns:

```
'\n\n     Band 1\t 0.428944\t0.843916\t0.689923\t
```

EDIT:

The original dataframes I posted are simplified and in reality there are more columns of data.

```
`print(repr(open(r'D:\Sheyenne\Statistics\NDVI_allotment\Text\A_Annex2.csv').read(500)))
```

returns:

```
'\nBasic Stats\t      Min\t     Max\t    Mean\t   Stdev\t  Num\tEigenvalue\n     Band 1\t 0.428944\t0.843916\t0.689923\t0.052534\t    1\t  0.229509\n     Band 2\t-0.000000\t0.689320\t0.513170\t0.048885\t    2\t  0.119217\n     Band 3\t 0.336438\t0.743478\t0.592622\t0.052544\t    3\t  0.059111\n     Band 4\t 0.313259\t0.678561\t0.525667\t0.048047\t    4\t  0.051338\n     Band 5\t 0.374522\t0.746828\t0.583513\t0.055989\t    5\t  0.027913\n     Band 6\t-0.000000\t0.749325\t0.330068\t0.314351\t    6\t  0.022561\n     Band 7\t-0.000000\t0.819288\t0.6001'
```

Comment: Could you show us a sample of the file too please? `print(repr(open('file.txt').read(100)))` would be helpful here.

Comment: I Googled your question's title and came up with a few helpful results, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585337/how-to-use-tab-space-while-writing-in-text-file) (Java, but still relevant).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, I'm sorry but what do you mean by a sample?  The first block of code I showed is a sample of what it looks like, do you mean something different?

Comment: I mean something different; I'd like to see the raw data. I gave you a Python command that would produce the first 100 characters from the file.

Comment: That returns `'Filename: F:\\Sheyenne\\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\\Indices\\Main\\NDVI\\NDVI_stack\nROI: EVF: Layer'`.  But all that is is the first line of the txt file

Comment: The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) state that the default separator is a comma, your file contains tabs and no commas, you can try this: `df = pd.read_csv(r'file.txt', sep='\t')` as Martijn has answered already, it should then load your csv correctly, otherwise you have additional formatting issues, I suggest posting a link to your file or editing your question and pasting the exact input text to avoid abiguity

Comment: @StefanoPotter: please add that to your question, although if you could increase the number of characters that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I made it so it contains data in the frame now, I had just omitted the first two lines of the file in my example above for simplicity

Comment: Thanks for adding raw file data; I note that it is not 100 characters however. Still, there is enough info there that we can work with, I think.

Comment: yes, there are four more columns of data that I am going to end up removing from the file anyways, I can add the full 100 characters if you think it would help though

Comment: I added 500 characters of data from the original file in addition to the 42 characters I initially posted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a *tab character*. It means your `pandas.read_csv()` call failed to automatically determine the correct delimiter in the file.

You could try and specify it explicitly with the `sep` argument:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'file.txt', sep='\t')
```

or you could set the `delim_whitespace` argument to true for general whitespace-as-delimiter support:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'file.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

From your sample it looks like you have extra empty lines, as well as spaces after the delimiter, so perhaps you need to have the reader skip those:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'file.txt', sep='\t',
                 skipinitialspace=True, skip_blank_lines=True)
```

See the [documentation on handling CSV files](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files).

Comment: Note that `delim_whitespace=True` would likely cause problems with the OP's data (the space in "Band 1").

Comment: @DSM: Yup, unless `read_csv` can handle quoting like the Python `csv` module can *and* that first column is using quoting (which may not be the case since the `\t` is included in that column).

Comment: @DSM: at any rate, without a sample of the file we are all just guessing here anyway. I asked for one.

Comment: using `sep='\t'` returns the error `CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 7 `

Comment: @StefanoPotter: your 100 character sample doesn't contain any tabs, but then again it doesn't contain any of the data in your frame output either.

Answer (score 2):

`\` is an escape character. It alters the representation of the following character. In the case of `\t`, it becomes a tabspace. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Answer (score 1):

`\t` is the escape sequence for a `<tab>` character.

Comment: I guess answering the question "What does \t represent in txt file?" is worthy of a down vote today.

Comment: Or maybe just 1 upvote. (But just one) Ps. I see adding the Wikipedia link is worth 10xp :)